# Changing htdocs directory xampp causing error

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I'm working on mac 10.6.8 and I've installed xampp and would like to change where the htdocs files are looked for. I have changed the **httpd.conf file in the etc folder within xampp**

so the lines now read:

> DocumentRoot "/WorkArea/folderforhtml"

I've also changed the directory to that folder

> Directory "/WorkArea/folderforhtml"

I've put a test.html folder in that file but when I go to my localhost/test.html I'm getting a 403 error. Is there a permission setting I need to change in order to access these files?

I've restarted the server many times as well.